# Check if username exists in table with password

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, callable-statement

I have created a login system that check for tries before blocks an account in case password fails more than three times. The problem is that I need to check if the username exists and if not, print a message saying that the id doesn't exists; but I don't know what to do. I mean, I have the idea of how to do it, but I don't know how to do it on Java.

Theese are my stored precedures

**Login**

```
create proc usp_Login
   @id varchar(50),
   @pw varchar(50)
as
   select id, pw from Login where id = @id and pw = @pw and lock = 0 and tries < 4
   update Login set tries = 0 where id = @id and pw = @pw;
```

**Attempts**

```
create proc usp_Attempts
   @id varchar(50)
as
   select id, tries from Login where id = @id and tries < 4
   update Login set tries = tries+1 where tries < 4 and id = @id
```

**Block user**

```
create proc usp_Lock
   @id varchar(50)
as
   update Login set lock = 1 where id = @id
```

**And the java part is like this:**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        CallableStatement cStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call usp_Login(?, ?)}");
            cStmt.setString(1, this.txtID.getText());
            cStmt.setString(2, this.txtPW.getText());
            cStmt.execute();

            rs = cStmt.getResultSet();

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Login done");
                cStmt.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();
            } else {
                cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call usp_Attempts(?)}");
                cStmt.setString(1, this.txtID.getText());
                cStmt.execute();

                rs = cStmt.getResultSet();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid login");
                } else {
                    cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call usp_Lock(?)}");
                    cStmt.setString(1, this.txtID.getText());
                    cStmt.execute();

                    System.out.println("Login blocked");
                    cStmt.close();
                    rs.close();
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
    }
```

I know that maybe this is not the best way to do a login system, but I'm still learning and this is by now the best idea I got about doing it.
Hope someone can help me to do the id verification part,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to review how to "securely" store passwords.. I would separate the auth from the lockout process; then the "Username or Password is invalid" is trivially detected. To add explicitly if a Username is invalid, check that independently of the other criteria.

Comment: In general, ive never done the "tries and block" part in the DB, but you should check asynchronous encrypting for the password, and just reset the user attempts to 0 when successful if it hasnt been blocked. Sorry i couldnt be of much help.

Comment: I didn't take in mind the password protection, thank you guys for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all this logic into one single stored procedure (SP). At the very end of the body of this SP just do `SELECT v AS RESULT;` where v is some integer value. Make this value v different depending on the login attempt outcome e.g.

- v=0 means login succeeded;
- v=1 means login failed as there's no such username;
- v=2 means login failed as the account was already locked when this login was attempted;
- v=3 means login failed as the password does not match, but the SP did not lock the account;
- v=4 means login failed as the password does not match, and also the SP has just locked the account due to too many tries.

Of course through the `RESULT` value, you can encode other login attempt outcomes in any way you like. Then in the Java code just inspect the SP `RESULT` value to know exactly what happened inside it during this login attempt. That is in the Java code you will get a result set with 1 row and 1 column called `RESULT`, just inspect its value and proceed the way you like.

Comment: I did what you said and it is working like charm now!
Thank you very much, sir.